# How to split the string by using given number with whitespaces?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like below,

```
String str = "12 67 239 2 47 29";
```

Here i want to split the above string by using `" 2 "`

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.split(str, " 2 ")[0]);
```

I got a result,  `1`.

But i want the result like below,

```
12 67 239 2
```

How can i do it guys, Please help me.

Comment: I think what you want is to get a `substring` of the string and not to `split` the string. You can easily do that by implementing a regular expression. It is best that you post the code that you have tried.

Comment: You are writting on console the first position of your array, not the whole array. Furthermore, I agree with Aradhna, you just don't want to split the string

Comment: @Aradhna why not to split, `str.split("(?<=\\s2)\\s+")[0]`, split accepts a regex as it's first argument.

Comment: for matching this regex would be enough `.*?\\b2\\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex to split the string on one or more spaces which exists next to 2.

```
str.split("(?<=\\s2)\\s+")[0]
```

- `(?<=\\s2)` positive lookbehind which looks next to the `<space>2`
- `\\s+` matches one or more spaces.
- Since the split will occur only on the matched characters, the above string should be splitted using the space which exists next to 2 as delimiter.

or

Remove all the characters which exists next to 2.

```
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("(\\s2)\\s+.*", "\\1"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Avinash Raj. It's working fine.  I have one doubt, in third point which you mentioned in answer, did this work for delimiter with prefix and suffix with white space right?

Comment: Could you please provide the reference (or) tutorial link for "Regular Expression" .

Comment: @kanna yep, but it would do split on the suffix whitespace. this site covers almost every regex https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html